# How do you setup Visual Studio 2005 to use #ifdef _MSC_VER?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I am trying to use the _MSC_VER macro in a Visual Studio 2005.NET C++ project, but am unable to use #ifdef _MSC_VER.  Does anyone know how to setup a Visual Studio 2005 project to be able to use this macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is documented as a [predefined macro here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(VS.80).aspx).  I use it like this:

```
#if _MSC_VER >= 1400
```